# JavaScript – Continuidade de uma array usando operações aritméticas para encontrar o índice

Tags: javascript, array

No JavaScript, eu, usando no caso o *for loop* comum de iteração de *array* com a variável *i*, estou tentando criar um arranjo com sub-arranjos que tenham dados de outros arranjos a partir de uma ordem relativa à posição de *i*.

Este exemplo de código descreve situação:

```js
var arranjoBase1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var arranjoBase2 = ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
var arranjoBase3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var arranjoFinal = [ [], [], [], [], [] ]

for(i = 0; i < arranjoFinal.length; i++)
 { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase1[i], arranjoBase2[i], arranjoBase3[i]);
   if(i != 0) { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[i - 1]) }
    else { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[arranjoBase3.length - 1]) };
   if(i != arranjoBase3.length - 1) { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[i + 1]) }
    else { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[0]) };
   if(i == 0) { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[arranjoBase3.length - 2]) } 
    else if(i == 1) { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[arranjoBase3.length - 1 ]) }
    else { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[i - 2]) };
   if(i == arranjoBase3.length - 1) { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[1]) }
    else if(i == arranjoBase3.length - 2) { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[0]) }
    else { arranjoFinal[i].push(arranjoBase3[i + 2]) }  };

//Resultado Final
  var arranjoFinal = (5) [Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7), Array(7)]

//Exemplo de Arranjo Final
  var  arranjoFinal[0] = (7) ["a", "f", 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Esse código já me fornece os resultados desejados.

O ponto é que, como precisei usar muitas condicionais *if* para contornar o problema de se o resultado de uma das operações aritméticas para encontrar o próximo elemento a se adicionar no arranjoFinal estiver fora do índice do arranjoBase3 – caso em que seria retornado *undefined* no lugar do elemento desejado –, sinto que deve haver uma solução muito mais prática para se chegar a esse resultado, que, por exemplo, também seja sustentável para arranjos maiores do que cinco elementos.

Assim, haveria de fato uma forma mais [prática/concisa] de se alcançar resultados como esses? Como, por exemplo e preferencialmente, uma forma de dizer que, se o resultado de uma operação aritmética para encontrar o índice do elemento de uma *array* ultrapassar o índice dessa *array* isso significa que é para ela dar continuidade à operação a partir do seu [início/final]?

Comment: Poderia explicar mais detalhadamente o que o código deveria fazer ou faz atualmente? se possível como se fosse a explicação dada para algum desenvolvedor que fosse desenvolver essa tarefa pra você. Assim surgirá uma solução possívelmente bem diferente da sua e pode ser que seja melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Certo, vamos lá:

Acredito que suas condições sejam os menores dos seus problemas.

Não tentei melhorar as condições porque estava um pouco confuso, acredito que você precisa pensar numa lógica melhor.

Mas a questão é melhorar as práticas de javascript nesse código.

Uma função que vai ajudar muito sua vida é a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), ela retorna um novo array a partir do seu array de entrada (o array original não é modificado, o que significa muito em programação funcional).

Suas comparações deveriam ser === ao invés de == para evitar conversão de tipo já que você sabe que as variáveis que você está comparando são números.

Use [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) ou [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), var já está em desuso. No meu exemplo é utilizei só const porque apesar de ter que alterar os elementos de um array eu não alterei o endereço de memória dele.

Melhore sua identação: seus condicionais estão bem difíceis de entender, não coloque ponto e vírgula no final de um else. Te aconselho a utilizar o [eslint](https://eslint.org/) que fornece regras para codificação e acaba te ensinando a programar melhor.

Como última dica, aprenda programação funcional e veja porque não mutar uma variável de entrada é importante para melhor manutenção e debug do seu código e aprenda javascript na versão 6.

Eu fiz um código utilizando arrow functions que é da versão 6 e já funciona no chrome e no firefox:

```
const arranjoBase1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
const arranjoBase2 = ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
const arranjoBase3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const arranjoBase = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

const arranjoMap = arranjoBase.map((el, i) => {
    const arranjoParte1 = [arranjoBase1[i], arranjoBase2[i], arranjoBase3[i]];
    const arranjoParte2 = [];

  if (i !== 0) {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[i - 1]);
  } else {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[arranjoBase3.length - 1]);
  }

  if(i !== arranjoBase3.length - 1) {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[i + 1]);
  }
  else {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[0]);
  }

  if (i === 0) {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[arranjoBase3.length - 2]);
  } else if (i === 1) {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[arranjoBase3.length - 1 ]);
  } else {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[i - 2]);
  }

  if (i === arranjoBase3.length - 1) {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[1]);
  }
  else if (i === arranjoBase3.length - 2) {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[0]);
  } else {
    arranjoParte2.push(arranjoBase3[i + 2]);
  }

  return arranjoParte1.concat(arranjoParte2);
});
```

Como eu vou usar o map, só preciso de um array com o número de elementos que você precisa. Como você precisa somente dos valores dos outros 3 arrays o valor do array não importa.

O arranjoParte1 é sempre fixo e o arranjoParte2 é tratado nas condição. A cada interação eu retorno um array com a concatenação dos dois.

Na versão 5 eu uso concat para concatenar, na versão 6 eu posso simplesmente usar esse comando:

```
[...arranjoParte1, ...arranjoParte2]
```

[Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/p6svtew2/1/) está um exemplo funcionando, porque afinal falar é fácil né ;)